# PDO query assistance

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So im moving my queries to PDO , and im learning step by step.

I figured buy trial and error, that unlike in normale mysql_ you cannot do a while in a while etc.

so im trying to join tables in a query to get a expected result.

The following query works

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT nieuws.id, nieuws.titel, nieuws.intro, nieuws.inhoud,    nieuws.datum, nieuws.auteur, nieuws.categorie, nieuws.tags,nieuws.plaatje, nieuws.plaatje_url,nieuws.mp3,nieuws.mp3_url,nieuws.youtube,nieuws.youtube_url, reacties.id, reacties.nieuwsid, reacties.submitter,reacties.reactie
FROM nieuws 
INNER JOIN reacties
ON nieuws.id = reacties.nieuwsid
ORDER BY reacties.nieuwsid DESC LIMIT 3
');
```

However, this only returns 1 entry, i want the query to return all "nieuws" entrys, and the corrosponding "reacties" (based upon id)

Translating dutch words to english : Nieuws = news, reacties = comment

So it needs to get id1 with all data for instance and also get nieuwsid1 data.
and then do this for all idx results

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC limit 3');
```

gets all the news, howver i do not have any reactions, and since im getting the article etc in the

```
foreach($data as $row)
```

loop i cannot start a second foreach right?

Comment: Why wouldn't you? the query has been executed, you're using the resultset that PDO returned, feel free to query a second time. However, a JOIN would be a better fit in your case... Just work on your query, if needs must, use `GROUP_CONCAT`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're using an `INNER JOIN`, which only returns entries from table A that have entries in table B, so if a "News" item doesn't have any comments, it won't be returned.

What you want is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: thnx Greg, could you elaborate on LEFT OUTER JOIN, google doesnt seem to want to be helpfull today.

Comment: I've always found this to be helpful - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: i already found another link, will read your too tho... thnx man left outer join was the key

Comment: SELECT * FROM nieuws LEFT OUTER JOIN reacties ON nieuws.id  = reacties.nieuwsid ORDER by nieuws.id DESC LIMIT 3

Comment: thats what im trying now, however when i do a sprintf($row['id']);

Comment: aparently im still missing something?

Comment: reacties.id and reacties.nieuwsid , i have 2 entrys wich share ofcourse reacties.nieuwsid , but it only shows me one entry when i do a print_r($row[reactie]);

Comment: it does however then repeat the news.inhoud twice, where it needs to do the reacties twice

Comment: argh im to used to doing while in a while loop :/ i suck i know

Comment: whenever i start a foreach within a foreach it nullifies? the first foreach? :S better start reading on .......

Comment: hmm ofcourse, it wont show it, because there is no reaction right? :/ damn

Comment: Honestly, I haven't done much with PHP/PDO in a couple of years, so I don't remember the specifics of looping through the results. :(

Comment: i managed to fix it myself, i decided to stop guessing for answers, and start reading all the tuts i could find, makes a difference tho .... :)